# PyQt - QTabWidget doesn't change language all tab when use Qt Linguist

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget, qt-linguist

I'm facing an issue. I use Qt Linguist for multi language app. If use for QWidget, it work well. But when i use with QTabWidget, it just change language in one tab, other tab do not update language. Anyone help me, please

Example: I have button in tab 1, when i press that button, i want to change language in all tab. But just tab 1 change, other tab do not change.  See my code

My Main Window

```
import os
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QLocale, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QTabWidget

from screen_one import ScreenOne
from src.screen_two import ScreenTwo
from src.tab_one import TabOne
from src.tab_two import TabTwo


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.current_locale = QLocale.system().name()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.central_layout)

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.screen_one = ScreenOne()
        self.screen_one.click_signal.connect(self.change_language)
        self.screen_two = ScreenTwo()
        self.tab_one = TabOne()
        self.tab_two = TabTwo()

        # Add tabs to the tab widget
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.screen_one, "Tab 1")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.screen_two, "Tab 2")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab_one, "Tab 3")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab_two, "Tab 4")

        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def change_language(self):
        qtranslator = QTranslator()
        translator.load("/path/main_vi.qm")
        QCoreApplication.instance().installTranslator(qtranslator)
        self.retranslateUi()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        # Update the text of the label and button
        for index in range(self.tab_widget.count()):
            self.tab_widget.widget(index).retranslateUi()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and install the translator
    translator = QTranslator()
    translator.load("/path/main_en.qm")
    app.installTranslator(translator)

    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My Screen One, which have button to change language:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QImage
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QCoreApplication, Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,  QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

class ScreenOne(QWidget):
    click_signal = Signal(bool)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        # create label
        self.mylabel = QLabel(self.tr("This is screen 1"))
        # center
        self.mylabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.tr("Hello 1"))

        # create label
        self.mylabel = QLabel(self.tr("Qt Init Widget"))
        # center
        self.mylabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label_1 = QLabel(self.tr("This is a QLabel 1"))
        self.button_1 = QPushButton(self.tr("Press me 1"))
        self.button_2 = QPushButton(self.tr("Press me 2"))
        self.button_3 = QPushButton(self.tr("Press me 3"))
        self.button_change_language = QPushButton(self.tr("Change Language"))
        self.button_change_language.clicked.connect(self.change_language)

        # create layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)


        self.layout.addWidget(self.mylabel)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_change_language)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def change_language(self):
        self.click_signal.emit(True)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.mylabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", u"This is screen 1", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", u"Hello 1", None))
        self.label_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", u"This is a QLabel 1", None))
        self.button_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", "Press me 1", None))
        self.button_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", "Press me 2", None))
        self.button_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", "Press me 3", None))
        self.button_change_language.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", "Change Language", None))
```

My Screen Two, Other Screen similar with Screen two:
import sys

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QImage
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QCoreApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,  QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout

class ScreenTwo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        # create label
        self.mylabel = QLabel(self.tr("This is screen 2"))
        # center
        self.mylabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.tr("Hello 2"))

        # create layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.mylabel)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.mylabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", u"This is screen 2", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("", u"Hello 2", None))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an extremely basic [mre] (just a couple of text affected widgets, and all within a single code block) and include the related ts files so that we can check them more easily?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. That's my bad, in retranslateUi() function, must pass the context parameter.

```
 def retranslateUi(self):
    self.mylabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("ScreenOne", u"This is screen 1", None))
    self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("ScreenOne", u"Hello 1", None))
```

Similar for other screen.